# sizeof aligned empty struct

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment, sizeof, c++14

I found, that aligned empty struct have a size strictly equal to its alignment ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34ba1adcfc6910f2)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdlib>

template< std::size_t i >
struct alignas(1 << i) aligned_storage
{

};

template< std::size_t ...I >
constexpr
void
test(std::index_sequence< I... >)
{
    static_assert(((sizeof(aligned_storage< I >) == (1 << I)) && ...));
}

int
main()
{
    test(std::make_index_sequence< 29 >{});
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is it well formed [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25fb9b68bd094ecb) (especially placement `new`s) (**?**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cstdlib>

template< std::size_t argument, std::size_t base = 2, bool = (argument < base) >
constexpr std::size_t log = 1 + log< (argument / base), base >;

template< std::size_t argument, std::size_t base >
constexpr std::size_t log< argument, base, true > = 0;

template< typename ...types >
struct alignas(2 << std::max({log< sizeof(types) - 1 >...})) aligned_storage
{

};

struct A
{
    int j;
    A(int i) : j(i) { std::cout << j << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << j << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; } 
};

struct B
{
    short j;
    B(short i) : j(i) { std::cout << j << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << j << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; } 
};

int
main()
{
    aligned_storage< A, B > storage;
    auto a = ::new (&storage) A{1};
    a->~A();
    auto b = ::new (&storage) B{2};
    b->~B();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is it permittable in *C++* to use above `struct` instead of `std::aligned_storage_t`?

Comment: Wheel-reinventing much? Also, over-aligned types are not guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: @T.C. Does it mean that not all the platforms supports `alignas` keyword properly?

Comment: Any alignment greater than `alignof(std::max_align_t)` need not be supported by the implementation. See [basic.align]/p3.

Comment: You know you can write `alignas(types...)` instead of resorting to such (not quite right) contraptions - it's been in the standard since C++11, it's been supported by Clang for a while now, MSVC 14 RC also supports it, GCC 5.1.0 doesn't, but 6.0.0 does. If you only have some types (not a parameter pack), you can write `alignas(A) alignas(B)` and so on, as they syntactically form an *attribute-specifier-seq*.

Comment: @bogdan I don't know yet. Thank you for the info. But for types like `char [100]` simple `alignas(char [100])` don't work.

Comment: `alignas(char[100])` works perfectly and specifies an alignment of `1`, which is correct. What alignment would you be looking for?

Comment: @bogdan `sizeof(struct alignas(char[100]) {}) == 1`

Comment: @bogdan I looking for alignment equal to ceil of log2 of size of largest type.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, that's the correct alignment for a `char[100]`. From your solution, it doesn't look like "ceil of log2 of size" is what you're looking for, but rather "smallest power of 2 larger than size". I have to ask: why do you want to align objects that way?

Comment: @bogdan What I want is clearly evident from the code in question. I want to have properly aligned struct of such size, that it can contain any of types from list. Do you know what `std::aligned_storage_t` for? The purpose is exactly the same. I know that there is overhead in general case and for types `T: sizeof(T) == 1`, but it does not matter for me.

Comment: @bogdan WRT meaning of parameter of latter `alignas` from question: you are right.

Comment: I didn't ask *what*, I asked *why*, which is not evident at all. `alignas(types...)` will give your type the proper alignment, in a standard-compliant and easy way; setting the right size is separate from alignment, and really easy. That's why `std::aligned_storage` has two template parameters. *Why* would you want to align objects based on their full size, rather than their actual alignment requirements?

Comment: @bogdan I exploited `alignas` to set required size of empty struct.

Comment: Yes, but you messed up the alignment in the process, instead of using a member of type `char[my_size]`, which gives you exactly what you want in a simple way. Anyway, you [said above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648821/sizeof-aligned-empty-struct#comment49386102_30648821) that you're "looking for alignment equal to [...]"; now it looks like that wasn't really a requirement, but just an exercise in exploiting a language feature (for no gain whatsoever, but rather for a loss). Is that all there is to it?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

> When applied to a class type, the result is the size of an object of
> that class plus any additional padding required to place such object
> in an array.
>
> When applied to an empty class type, always returns 1.

An equivalent interpretation is `sizeof(type[N])==sizeof(type)*N` is required by standard to be always `true`. This will cause the result of `sizeof` to be always the greater one of the actual memory representation size and the alignment.